# react webpack app often got a blanc page after reload

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, webpack

my reactjs app runs with webpack at the moment. I have the problem when I save changes in intellij the site will be recompiled. but not loaded again

when I'm under url localhost:8080/dashboard/new it reloads but got white page with error in console:

```
all:32 GET http://localhost:8080/dashboard/bundle.js
```

I have to manualle reload the page with root url http://localhost:8080 to get the paged renedered.

what could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: does the same thing happen when you edit your files in a different editor? The only thing in WebStorm that can affect webpack hot reloading is 'safe writes' - webpack 1.* doesn't play well with it (https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#working-with-editors-ides-supporting-safe-write)

Comment: If you use webpack dev server you should set `historyApiFallback` to `true`

Comment: in the webpack config or where?

Comment: already haf historyApiFallback on true ...

Comment: historyApiFallback is already on true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me is:

```
class Processes extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/new`} component={ProcessesNew} />
                <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}`} exact component={ProcessesAll} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Processes;
```